# Jsoup - extract html from element

Tags: android, html-parsing, jsoup

I want to extract HTML code from a div element using **jsoup** HTML parser library.

HTML code:

```
<div class="entry-content">
   <div class="entry-body">
      <p><strong>Text 1</strong></p>
      <p><strong> <a class="asset-img-link" href="http://example.com" style="display: inline;"><img alt="IMG_7519" class="asset  asset-image at-xid-6a00d8341c648253ef01b7c8114e72970b img-responsive" src="http://example.com" style="width: 500px;" title="IMG_7519" /></a><br /></strong></p>
      <p><em>Text 2</em> </p>
   </div>
</div>
```

Extract part:

```
String content = ... the content of the HTML from above
Document doc = Jsoup.parse(content);
Element el = doc.select("div.entry-body").first();
```

I want to the result `el.html()` to be the whole HTML from div tab entry-body:

```
<p><strong>Text 1</strong></p>
  <p><strong> <a class="asset-img-link" href="http://example.com" style="display: inline;"><img alt="IMG_7519" class="asset  asset-image at-xid-6a00d8341c648253ef01b7c8114e72970b img-responsive" src="http://example.com" style="width: 500px;" title="IMG_7519" /></a><br /></strong></p>
  <p><em>Text 2</em> </p>
```

but I get only the first `<p>` tag:

```
<p><strong>Text 1</strong></p>
```

Comment: The problem is not reproducible for me. If I do exactly as you stated I do get  all inner HTML just fine. Which version of JSoup are you using? My check was done with version 1.8.3

Comment: I'm using also 1.8.3 - last version and it dosn't work... You get the result the entire `div` content ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments to the OP, I don't get it. Here is my reproduction of the problem, and it does exactly what you want:

```
String html = ""
    +"<div class=\"entry-content\">"
    +"   <div class=\"entry-body\">"
    +"      <p><strong>Text 1</strong></p>"
    +"      <p><strong> <a class=\"asset-img-link\" href=\"http://example.com\" style=\"display: inline;\"><img alt=\"IMG_7519\" class=\"asset  asset-image at-xid-6a00d8341c648253ef01b7c8114e72970b img-responsive\" src=\"http://example.com\" style=\"width: 500px;\" title=\"IMG_7519\" /></a><br /></strong></p>"
    +"      <p><em>Text 2</em> </p>"
    +"   </div>"
    +"</div>"
    ;
Document doc = Jsoup.parse(html);
Element el = doc.select("div.entry-body").first();
System.out.println(el.html());
```

This results in the following output:

```
<p><strong>Text 1</strong></p> 
<p><strong> <a class="asset-img-link" href="http://example.com" style="display: inline;"><img alt="IMG_7519" class="asset  asset-image at-xid-6a00d8341c648253ef01b7c8114e72970b img-responsive" src="http://example.com" style="width: 500px;" title="IMG_7519"></a><br></strong></p> 
<p><em>Text 2</em> </p>
```

Comment: Seems that was my stupid mistake.... I had in logcat some filters and that's why I could not see only the first line ... Sorry all about this confusion and thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
Elements el = doc.select("div.entry-body");
```

instead of this:

```
Element el = doc.select("div.entry-body").first();
```

and then:

```
for(Element e : el){
    e.html();
}
```

**EDIT**

Maybe you'll get you result if you do that this way: 
I have try to do it and it give a correct result.
    `Elements el = doc.select("a.asset-img-link");`

Comment: It doesn not work.. `el.size()` is 1 and only prints `<p><strong>Text 1</strong></p>`

Answer (score 1):

In your case, you'd use

```
  doc.select("div[name=entry-body]") to select that specific <div>
```

acording to this [cookbook](http://jsoup.org/cookbook/extracting-data/selector-syntax)

Comment: It doesn not work - it returns 0 elements. According to documentation you states, `el.class: elements with class, e.g. div.masthead` should be used, but this doesn't get me the entire `div` content..

Comment: **EDIT**

Maybe you'll get you result if you do that this way: 
I have try to do it and it give a correct result.
    `Elements el = doc.select("a.asset-img-link");`